# Using Golang to read csv, reorder columns then write result to a new csv with Concurrency

Tags: csv, go, concurrency

Here's my starting point.

It is a Golang script to read in a csv with 3 columns, re-order the columns and write the result to a new csv file.

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "encoding/csv"
   "io"
   "os"
   "math/rand"
   "time"
)

func main(){
  start_time := time.Now()

  // Loading csv file
  rFile, err := os.Open("data/small.csv") //3 columns
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    return
   }
  defer rFile.Close()

  // Creating csv reader
  reader := csv.NewReader(rFile)

  lines, err := reader.ReadAll()
  if err == io.EOF {
      fmt.Println("Error:", err)
      return
  }

  // Creating csv writer
  wFile, err := os.Create("data/result.csv")
  if err != nil {
      fmt.Println("Error:",err)
      return
  }
  defer wFile.Close()
  writer := csv.NewWriter(wFile)

  // Read data, randomize columns and write new lines to results.csv
  rand.Seed(int64(time.Now().Nanosecond()))
  var col_index []int
  for i,line :=range lines{
      if i == 0 {
        //randomize column index based on the number of columns recorded in the 1st line
        col_index = rand.Perm(len(line))
    }
    writer.Write([]string{line[col_index[0]], line[col_index[1]], line[col_index[2]]}) //3 columns
    writer.Flush()
}

//print report
fmt.Println("No. of lines: ",len(lines))
fmt.Println("Time taken: ", time.Since(start_time))

}
```

**Question:**

1. Is my code idiomatic for Golang?
2. How can I add concurrency to this code?

Comment: You can't read or write individual files concurrently, and when the data processing is going to be so much faster than the IO there's little benefit in making the reading of one file concurrent with writing of another. If the files are huge it may be worth it, but get a working example first to understand the basics.

Comment: This may be better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JimB Ah, i did not know reading/writing files could not be done concurrently. If I fleshed out my randomizing of columns as a separate method e.g. func RandomizeColumns([] string), could I split my Reader object into 2 streams and apply RandomizeColumns() on both concurrently? 

I.e. can I split a csv.Reader() object into 2?

Comment: @JimB Wrong. You can read a file in a goroutine while you write to another file in another goroutine. Will it make your program faster? It depends.

Comment: @dolmen: I meant that concurrent readers will not help, and often hurt sequential io. People often think "I can read this faster if I have more readers", which isn't the case. Yes, you can even have multiple readers at different offsets, which may help in specific cases, but the OP obviously needs to start at the basics here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is OK. There are no much case for concurrency. But you can at least reduce memory consumption reordering on the fly. Just use `Read()` instead of `ReadAll()` to avoid allocating slice for hole input file.

```
for line, err := reader.Read(); err == nil; line, err = reader.Read(){
    if err = writer.Write([]string{line[col_index[0]], line[col_index[1]], line[col_index[2]]}); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error:", err)
            break
    }
    writer.Flush()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the improvement! I consider your response an adequate answer to my question. I'm a little disappointed that this use case has no need for concurrency, but I'll go look for another exercise to practice that.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `col_index` initialisation outside the write loop:

```
if len(lines) > 0 {
    //randomize column index based on the number of columns recorded in the 1st line
    col_index := rand.Perm(len(lines[0]))
    newLine := make([]string, len(col_index))

    for _, line :=range lines[1:] {
        for from, to := range col_index {
            newLine[to] = line[from]
        }
        writer.Write(newLine)
        writer.Flush()
    }
}
```

To use concurrency, you must not use `reader.ReadAll`. Instead make a goroutine that calls `reader.Read` and write the output on a channel that would replace the `lines` array. The main goroutine would read the channel   and do the shuffle and the write.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to review my code + explain a possible solution involving concurrency.