# How this error handling works. CSV file reading and writing case

Tags: go, error-handling

I'm learning how to read and write CSV files and error handling in Go.

I found a query whose answer I do not understand.

[Using Golang to read csv, reorder columns then write result to a new csv with Concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41938068/using-golang-to-read-csv-reorder-columns-then-write-result-to-a-new-csv-with-co)

The answer is

```
for line, err: = reader.Read (); err == nil; line, err = reader.Read () {
    if err = writer.Write ([] string {line [col_index [0]], line [col_index [1]], line [col_index [2]]}); err! = nil {
            fmt.Println ("Error:", err)
            break
    }
    writer.Flush ()
}
```

Why error equals the return of writer.Write()?

I'm used to seeing only

```
err! = nil {
            fmt.Println ("Error:", err)
            break
    }
```

Could you explain it to me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read until the end of the line, **this is an [if statement](https://golang.org/ref/spec#If_statements) with an assignment executed before the comparison**.

Shortening the `Write` call, this is:

```
if err = writer.Write(...); err != nil {
```

This first assigns the return value of `writer.Write` to `err`, then checks it against nil.

**An important note**: the equal operator is `==`, not `=`.

Another note: you should run `gofmt` on your code, `!=` and `:=` should not have a space in the middle. In fact, your spacing is all over the place.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the components of the first line:

```
for line, err: = reader.Read ();  // Declare err and assign to the result of Read
err == nil;  // Continue looping while err==nil
line, err = reader.Read ()  // Read again, and assign err
{
```

The above for-loop will continue looping reading lines while err==nil.

Then:

```
 if err = writer.Write (...); err! = nil {
```

This is using the same `err` created in the for-loop. It will simply break the loop if `Write` returns an error.